# Log when processes' priorities change

Tags: windows-7, logs

I am looking for a program that works with Windows that can log whenever processes (or threads) change of [priority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Windows). E.g. the log would look something like:

```
Datetime, process name, old priority, new priority
2014-07-25 01:02, C:\Program Files\Vuze\Azureus.exe, 10, 15
2014-07-25 01:05, C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin\matlab.exe ,24, 9
etc
```

If possible, free and works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing [python](http://www.python.org) and [psutils](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) then you can have a script that runs every so often, (say 10 secs or faster), and queries the processes that are running and if the priority has changed writes your log entry with whatever information you desire.  See the documentation for [psutil.process_iter()](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#Processes) and [get_nice()](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#Classes).

- Free (both Gratis and FOSS).
- Will run on Windows from XP to 8, Max OS(X), Linux, Unix and more.
- You easily can customise the information that you need.
- You can save your log in csv format for easy import to a spreadsheet.